# How to display a fragment in an activity running from a service?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've created a service for handling firebase cloud messaging by extending FirebaseMessagingService. Now I want to display a fragment in the bottom of the running activity. There are multiple activities. I want the fragment should pop up in the activity which is visible to the user at the time when the notification is received in the onMessageReceived() method of the service extending FirebaseMessagingService. I don't know how to do this.

This is the Service Class:

```
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Map;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFCMService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());



            //Display Fragment with the Message Data Payload



        }
    }
}
```

I've created a fragment class and want to display the fragment on any of the activity which is visible to the user. How can I do this?

Comment: You could something try this, Register a custom `IntentFilter` in your Activities, `onMessageRecieved()` => send a local broadcast with that custom `IntentFilter` you created & when the local broadcast is received, check if the App is in foreground, if `true` then Add & Show your Fragment. You can also use `EventBus` instead of `LocalBroadcastManager`

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I can suggest is to:

- Create a custom Broadcast Receiver that uses your custom bottom fragment
- Register that broadcast Receiver statically for brevity or in each Activity if there are many that listen to custom IntentFilter
- Send Local Broadcast when you received new message(s) from Firebase